# Can't call aspectj on jsp

Tags: jsp, aspectj

I want to weave jsp file on tomcat6. I write an aspect:

```
public aspect LoggingAspect {
    public pointcut requestcall() : call(* *.getParameter(..)) && 
        within(LoggingAspect);

Object around() : requestcall() {
    Signature sig = thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature();
    System.out.println("Start2 [" + sig.getDeclaringType().getName() +
     "." + sig.getName() + "]");

    Object ret = proceed();

    System.out.println("End2 [" + sig.getDeclaringType().getName() + "."
            + sig.getName() + "]");
    return (ret instanceof String) ? ((String) ret).toUpperCase() : ret;
    }
}
```

and jsp code is:

```
<body>
<%=request.getParameter("param") %>
</body>
```

but it wasn't called.

Comment: Sorry. i have solved the problem.
it was a mistake of VM argument option.
i have VM option to enter the "-javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar".
So the problem has been resolved.

Sorry but thanks.
Good Luck !!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must use Load Time Weaver, but you can do the same thing by wrapping your request with a Servlet Filter.

Comment: Amir Pashazadeh. yes! servlet filter can filtering request, but i want to use aspectj.